# Operator Precedence in Java, I can't find out the result

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me why the result is 30?

```
System.out.println(30 - 12 / (2*5) +1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple [arithmetic order of operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Arithmetic/Order_of_Operations).  `30 - 12 / (2 * 5) + 1` breaks down thus:

- Work the parentheses first:  `2 * 5` becomes `10`.  You now have `30 - 12 / 10 + 1`.
- Division takes precedence over all other present operators, so you're dividing 12/10 [as integers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2), so you'll get 1 as the quotient.  You now have `30 - 1 + 1`.
- You then subtract 30 from 1, then add 1 back to get 30.